# Rowdeleting event doesn't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and I have a button on it.I want, if the user click on a button on a row,this row will be delted.I did this steps but I have no success.could you please help me to solve my problem?

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            int k=int.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            Label1.Text = k.ToString();
        }
```

I wanted to see the value in a lable but no success( I think this event doesn't fire)

Comment: what does it **really** means: not success ??

Comment: If i click the button I can't see the value of k in the lable

Comment: How come you _think_ the event doesn't fire? Did you set a breakpoint and did it get hit?

Comment: If I click a button I cant see the value of **k**  in the lable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:

I like to specify my handlers in code-behind in Page_Init event, so it looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   gw.RowDeleting += new GridViewDeleteEventHandler(gw_RowDeleting);
}

void gw_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
   // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: that is a miss understanding,I 'll edit the subject.now I only wnt to see the value of k in a lable when i click the button but I think this event doesn't fire up

Comment: @Baper, can you provide your code for wiring up the event handler to the event?

Comment: hmmm sorry I'm a little bit new in asp.net.I thought if the user click this button this event fire up automatically.Where should I put another block of code?

Comment: Do you explain me a way to display a primary key of the record,which I click the button on it ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your data is coming from a database, but you haven't specified in your sample code that you are calling the delete method in your data access layer / EF / repository.

Perhaps reading this tutorial will help? http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/editing,-inserting,-and-deleting-data/an-overview-of-inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-cs

Comment: thnak you for your answer.I don't want to use the wizard to do this job.Do you know,know I dont want to implement my Delete methode ,now want only to see the **k** value in a lable